# Multiple if let in Swift

Tags: swift

I have written the code as follows where there are multiple `if let` conditions here. Is there a way to come up with better approach? Like `guard` statement?

```
if UserDefaults.exists(key: "class") {
    let myClass = xxxxx
    if let myClass = myClass {
       let yourClass = yyyyy
       if let yourClass = yourClass {
          let hisClass = zzzzz
          if let hisClass = hisClass {
                        
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Sweeper's `if` solution, you can also `guard`:

```
guard
    UserDefaults.exists(key: "class"),
    let myClass = xxxxx,
    let yourClass = yyyyy,
    let hisClass = zzzzz
else {
    return
}

// use them here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `,` to separate multiple condition in an `if` statement:

```
if UserDefaults.exists(key: "class"),
    let myClass = xxxxx,
    let yourClass = yyyyy,
    let hisClass = zzzzz {
    // you can use all three classes here!
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_if-statement):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid overly nested code, you can do it as follows instead with guard statements as you mentioned (assuming you are inside a function):

```
guard UserDefaults.exists(key: "class") else { return }
let myClass = xxxxx
guard let myClass = myClass else { return }
let yourClass = yyyyy
guard let yourClass = yourClass else { return }
let hisClass = zzzzz
if let hisClass = hisClass else { 
    // do something
}
```

Note that guard statements cannot fallthrough so this code has be inside a function and you need a return statement inside your else block.

Comment: @user2864740 What do you mean? It is formatted correctly.

Comment: You can do a single guard with multiple conditionals separated by a comma (like in @Sweeper's answer), which avoids the multiple `else { return }` statements